# output of goods ubercart3

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

please help to solve the problem.
ubercart3 by default displays the items through views, using the 2-cycle

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
<?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>
<?php print $item; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to bring goods through one cycle. help please